# Doxygen With Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

dose any one used doxygen to generate a Documentation for flutter project before ,
I know about dartdoc extension , but I need to generate it with doxygen format ,
I found someone generated a doc for main files in flutter , but I just searched too much to how i do it , and never found it ,
I wish someone could help ,

I tried with C++ and Java too , and nothing goes
[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What are the sources of the flutter project coded in? Where can we find a flutter project / example.

Comment: Doxygen v , 1.9.4 
i don't understand you about where is the source of flutter , it is in my Local btw @albert

Comment: i tried yesterday to select the C++ and it runs , but there's no result for lib files , the main resources of code , @albert

Comment: What I meant was what type of files (programing language used) is flutter using.  What / show the content of a typical (small) file. I don't know anything about flutter, I looked at Wikipedia and in the German version I saw some code, looks like a bit of java, best to set `EXTENSION_MAPPING = dart=java` also set `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` for a first test.

Comment: i tried it right now , it's do nothing , and show's nothing , 
i know maybe doxygen maybe not goes with dart , but i found a documentation for flutter made by it , so surly it can run it with me but i missed some steps maybe @albert

Comment: It looks like you might have missed something, but as said" I don't know anything about flutter". I think you should also add `*.dart` to the `FILE_PATTERNS` setting. Furthermore best is to post in your question a small example flutter file (as text) and also the results you see in the `run tab` of the doxygen wizard when enabling `condensed` and pushing `Show Configuration` or even better used the command line in the appropriate directory and give `doxygen -c Doxyfile`

Comment: okay I will , btw I'm really appreciate your help , thanks btw @albert

Comment: it's work !!!
Thank You So much , I'm really really appreciate it :D  , you can post the last comment of you as a answer to verify it .. @albert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to see results of files with extensions that are not directly supported by doxygen, but contain code in a language supported by doxygen a number of settings have to be set (in this case we have Flutter dart files that are actually Java / Java like files):

```
INPUT_FILTERS += *.dart
EXTENSION_<APPING = dart=java
```

When files are in a different directories or in subdirectories it is good to look at the settings:

```
INPUT = 
RECURSIVE=YES
```

as well.

In case a  a language is not supported directly but can be transformed in a language that is supported by doxygen it is good to look at the doxygen filter possibilities as well (settings like `INPUT_FILTER` etc.).